# How do I sprint in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen a couple of videos of people sprinting in Minecraft (1.8). How do you do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Double tap and hold your <kbd>W</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is: If you double tap the <kbd>W</kbd> key, You will sprint... but in newer versions the default key is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

Comment: I believe the second part of your answer is wrong; the `SHIFT` is used to crouch by default. However, they recently added the ability to re-map springing to a specific key instead of double tapping, and some YouTubers may have chosen the `SHIFT` for this.

Answer (score -3):

Press the <kbd>U</kbd> key to sprint in minecraft.

Comment: Do you use a mod to do that?  Because that's not the default behaviour.